# Delete till first occurrence of pipe "|" using sed

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, delete

I want to remove all characters before the next pipe "|" symbol. I tried suggestions on previous questions however that did not work for me. As an example.

I want to delete the **sequencenum=123** however the sequence number is dynamic and doesn't always equal 123, it could equal 934294. I could remove it by using "s/|sequence=123//g" or "s/|sequence=...//g" however I want to be able to delete all characters until the next pipe, "|".

Output:

```
2021-03-22T12:00:51.990368-04:00 8.8.8.8 time=1616428842|action=Detect|ifdir=inbound|origin=8.8.8.8|originsicname=CN\=Internet,O\=test|sequencenum=123|dst=1.1.1.1|proto=6|s_port=2231|service=80|src=9.9.9.9|src_machine_name=test@stackoverflow.com|src_user_name=user|user=testuser@stackoverflow.com|
```

Desired Output:

```
2021-03-22T12:00:51.990368-04:00 8.8.8.8 time=1616428842|action=Detect|ifdir=inbound|origin=8.8.8.8|originsicname=CN\=Internet,O\=test|dst=1.1.1.1|proto=6|s_port=2231|service=80|src=9.9.9.9|src_machine_name=test@stackoverflow.com|src_user_name=user|user=testuser@stackoverflow.com|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/|sequence=[^|]*//g'
```

Would delete all occurrences of `|sequence=` followed by a sequence of 0 or more characters other than `|` so up to (but not including) the next `|` or a non-character or the end of the line whichever comes first.

Comment: That actually worked, thanks a bunch!